# Code only executes once but should continue

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below should prevent the popup from closing if you mouseover it, or the button, however, it only works once on reload and then stops working.

```
$('.popover3-test').popover({
    placement:'bottom',
    template: $('.popover2'),
    trigger: 'manual',

    }).mouseenter(function(e) {
    $(this).popover('show');

    var t = null;

    $(".popover2, .popover3-test")
        .mouseleave(function() {
            t = setTimeout(function() {
                $('.popover2').hide();
            }, 1000); // Or however many milliseconds
        })
        .mouseenter(function() {
            if(t !== null)
                clearTimeout(t);
         });
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MnpWV/1/

Comment: Please rephrase your question

Comment: it works once, then stops working, i want it to continue working.

Comment: @watson remove the `clearTimeout` then it will work. http://jsfiddle.net/MnpWV/2/

Comment: The clearTimeout is what stops the popover from disappearing. It doesn't work without it.

Comment: This was not a real question until Rob's edit. Why should Rob have been the one to go to your fiddle and copy/paste the code? It's not that hard and it is a requirement to meet guidelines.

Comment: @Greg it might be worth actually putting constructive comments in and trying to find a solution rather than having a go at people on here for simple mistakes.

Comment: The problem is probably that the mouseenter is firing before the mouseleave, thus there is no timeout to clear.

Comment: @JonTaylor Jon, I had already voted to close and was in the middle of a comment when I saw that Rob had provided the code. You can't take back the vote so I left the comment. When I vote to close (or downvote, which is pretty rare), I always leave my reasoning because that *is* constructive. And there was no downvote, which would have been petty. It wasn't about "having a go", it was about being honest about my vote to close. So you didn't like my tone. I don't like lazy questions and I don't think it's right to encourage them. Save your sanctimony for someone who actually deserves it.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(".popover2, .popover3-test")
        .mouseleave(function() {
           $('.popover2').delay(1000).fadeOut('1000');
        }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MnpWV/8/

update:

```
$(".popover2").hover(function(e) {
    $(this).show()
}, function() {
    $('this').delay(1000).fadeOut('1000');
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MnpWV/16/

remove the `.popover3-test` which triggers the `mouseleave` event.

Comment: if you mouseover the popover ('.popover2') it should stay visible.

Comment: now, if you never hover over the .popover2, it never goes away.

Comment: I think the problem with my original code is that there are two mouseenters, maybe.